# Admin Menu Permissions

Tags: users, navigation, toolbar

I want to allow my editors to add taxonomy terms to vocabularies. But to do so, I need to give them the permission "Use the administration pages and help", but as soon as i do that, they also can see the menu item "Configuration" in addition to the menu item "Structure".

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

The taxonomy fact was just an example. I also need this for webforms, so it would be better to have a general solution for that then just for a single module since this problem will occure for every configuration that is stored below "Structure".

It got this fixed using: [Admin Links Access Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_links_access_filter)